# Persistent Variable in a session in PHP

Tags: php

I did:

```
<?php 
session_start();
//require_once ('connection.php');
$cart1 = array();
$cart2 = array();

$_SESSION['cart1'] = $cart1;
$_SESSION['cart2'] = $cart1;
array_push($_SESSION['cart1'],$sel);
print_r($_SESSION['cart1']);

?>
```

with `$sel` having a different value each time a form is selected but instead of appending to the array, it creates a fresh one with the new data. What I want to do is create a persistent array variable that I can keep modifying without it deleting and resetting to the new value. Just started using sessions and I’m out of options. Help please.

Comment: do you mean `$_SESSION['sel'] = array('stick what you want here');` which would persist across the session

Comment: no i mean $_SESSION['cart1'] with $sel being the name of the varying variable passed through a form thats supposed to be appended to the $SESSION['cart1'] array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're initializing your carts as empty arrays on every request, you need to only initialize if the session arrays don't already exist

```
<?php 
session_start();
//require_once ('connection.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart1'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart1'] = array();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart2'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart2'] = array();
}

array_push($_SESSION['cart1'],$sel);
print_r($_SESSION['cart1']);

?>
```